# Where should I store values for quick inexpensive access performance wise

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

My site is multilingual.
Businesses from US, Europe, Australia and UK can create a business listing and provide their fees.
Now a business from the US will provide his fee in US dollars, a European company in Euros and a UK company in British Pounds.

For example: a business provided his rate as 3000 USD.

But the visitor views the page from Europe and wishes to see the price in euros, so I need to convert the 3000 USD to Euros.
What I want is to store the exchange rate each week by polling a webservice such as this one: http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=10&CATID=2. And store this somewhere (my DB for example) and then do the conversion on-the-fly when rendering the page.

Now since a DB query is quite expensive I was wondering what would be the best place to store these exchange rates?

In the database? File system? 
I was also thinking of web.config, but I do want to automatically update the exchange rates instead of manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of value - expensive to get, but doesn't change often (I am specifically talking about exchange rates) can be cached.

Your web server most likely supports some sort of caching mechanism - add these to the web server cache to lookup.

In IIS, using ASP.NET you can you the [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) class as well as the [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/94xkskdf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) variable. `Cache` is preferable as you can set it to expire.

Comment: I'm running a weekly job where I update the values, so no need to expire the values I would think?
But, for example, Session object is available to current user only. Are both Cache and Application object values available to all users?

Thanks!

Comment: @Floran - Whether you do or do not need to expire is up to you - if the application doesn't reset within a week, you may want to have an expiration built in. `Cache` and `Application` are shared - the value set will be the value seen by all users.